# Assume that $P( A\mid B) < P( A)$ & $P( B\mid C) < P( B)$ . Is it true that $P(A\mid C)<P(A)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If $P( A\mid B) < P( A)$ & $P( B\mid C) < P( B)$ , then is it true that $P(A\mid C)< P(A)$,
where $P( A\mid B)$  is the conditional property of $A$ given $B$?

I tried the following:

- $P(A ∩ B) < P(A)P(B)$
- $P(A ∩ C) < P(A)P(C)$
- $P(C ∩ B) < P(C)P(B)$

by using $P(A\mid B)=P(A ∩ B)/P(B)$.
But it led me nowhere.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I assumed all three to be true and then searched for an inconsistency.

Comment: OK. And? What did you write?

Comment: I wrote what it is written,converted the conditional probability to sets but its not giving any contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "No". Try $A=(0,\frac12)$, $B=(\frac12,1)$, $C=(0,\frac12)$, in the probability space $\Omega=[0,1]$ endowed with the Borel sigma-algebra and the Lebesgue probability measure.

To see that both situations are possible, try $A=(0,\frac47)$, $B=(\frac17,\frac67)$, $C=(\frac37,1)$, in the same probability space.

Comment: That proof asserts the argument well by counter example,but is there a rigorous way to do so,without any examples

Comment: You mean? To prove that the result always holds although a counterexample exists? Or to prove that the reverse inequality always holds although a counterexample to it also exists?

Comment: To prove: "P(A|B)<P(A)P(B) & P(B|C)<P(B)P(C) always implies P(A|C)>=P(A)P(C)" without any example

Comment: But "P(A|B)<P(A)P(B) & P(B|C)<P(B)P(C)" DOES NOT imply "P(A|C)>=P(A)P(C)". As explained in my post, "P(A|B)<P(A)P(B) & P(B|C)<P(B)P(C)" implies neither "P(A|C)>=P(A)P(C)" nor "P(A|C)<P(A)P(C)". This implies nothing. Zilch. *Rien du tout*. Nada.